# "REST Request for URL" Snowflake ODBC login error

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata-sql-assistant

Has anyone ever seen this Snowflake ODBC login error message?

["REST Request for URL" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z23oy.png)

I use Teradata's SQL Assistant and Snowflake's ODBC drivers (snowflake32_odbc-2.20.3.msi) to log into my snowflake account. Most attempts work just fine; I enter my pw into the ODBC dialogue box and my browser a few seconds later launches two tabs in succession as it authenticates my username and pw. Every few days I get this error and it takes several reboots to log in.

Preliminary testing seems to indicate that if I wait 30 minutes or more after a reboot and logging into my companies' VPN before I attempt a login to Snowflake, it works.

Comment: I wish we had more of an error to go on.  Does the Snowflake ODBC Logs capture any more details?  

Have you tried upgrading Teradata's SQL Assistant and the ODBC driver to see if it helps?  I know there's some logic introduced in later versions of the ODBC driver which may help here.  

Also, are you using externalbrowser to authenticate (browser-based SSO)? You might give this a try: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#optional-using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication

Comment: Other than that, from just going by what you are saying that this issue is intermittent and potentially fixed by a reboot, that sounds suspiciously like some kind of networking issue.  I wonder if your networking team can help trace the traffic and see if there's any issues.  That's all my ideas! If you get more info, maybe we can help further in the forums.

Comment: Hi Suzy, yes exactly we set the Authentication box in the ODBC driver to "externalbrowser'. I'll see if a new version of the driver and software help and look for the logs.

Comment: I think you may be right...this may be a bandwidth issue. The times I'm trying to log in (home Wi-Fi, VPN, kids in the house) may be crushing the bandwidth so far that authentication is taking too long and it times out. I'll report back.